# React Live Clock AM PM in caps is not visible

Tags: reactjs, clock, live

I am using React Live clock and trying to use AM/PM mode of but the output is small and shows like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzFI8.png)

timeFormat = 'h:mm:ss A';

Comment: You want the text to be bigger?

Comment: Yes, the output is basically A not properly AM/PM

Comment: the bigger text is already visible with this string 'h:mm:ss A'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [react-live-clock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-live-clock), you can set the **style** attribute as described [here](https://pvoznyuk.github.io/react-live-clock/).

e.g. The following settings:

```
<Clock style={{fontSize: '10.5em'}}  format={'h:mm:ss A'} ticking={true} timezone={'US/Pacific'} />
```

generated this view: [image]

**Note:**

I uploaded the sample project to my github repository [here](https://github.com/naorbar/react-live-clock-example);

Follow the [README.MD](https://github.com/naorbar/react-live-clock-example/blob/master/README.md) file for details on how to clone and start the application locally.

**Goodluck!**

Comment: With exactly this code i am getting this 12:23:29 A

Comment: I uploaded this example to github: https://github.com/naorbar/react-live-clock-example; follow the README.MD for more details on how to start the application or work on it locally

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the project i can see in your project its working properly fine. And when i have implemented in my project its not working anymore. I guess maybe some other pages are somehow interrupting i have checked the CSS too. Might be something else

Comment: @Adeel, I can suggest you to delete your project's "node_modules" folder and "npm install" again, or remove your CSS files (they might overlap). If it doesn't help, start from scratch or use the cloned project... Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion and i am sure they are right because i searched alot about it. But i have got a alternate and designed my own Clock. But Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to format the date to change and A and P to AM and PM, respectively.

```js
var WithoutFormattingA = "8:11:35 A";
var WithoutFormattingP = "8:11:35 P";

function formatDate(unformattedDate) {
    var timeOfDay = unformattedDate.substr(unformattedDate.length - 1)

    if(timeOfDay === 'A' || timeOfDay === 'P') {
        return unformattedDate + "M";
    } else {
        return "Invalid date format.";
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <div>Formatted {WithoutFormattingA} to {formatDate(WithoutFormattingA)}</div>
    <div>Formatted {WithoutFormattingP} to {formatDate(WithoutFormattingP)}</div>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn but i am using the alternate clock

Answer (score 0):

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const WeatherApp = () => {
const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());

useEffect(() => {

```
var timer = setInterval(() => setTime(new Date()), 1000);

return function cleanup() {

  clearInterval(timer);

};
```

});

return (
<>

```
  <h3 style={{ paddingTop: '5px', fontSize: '5rem' }}>

    {time.getHours() >= 12 ? (

      <>
        {time.getHours() > 12 ? (

          <>

            {time.getHours() - 12 < 10 ? (

              <>0{time.getHours() - 12}</>

            ) : (
              <>{time.getHours() - 12}</>

            )}

          </>

        ) : (

          <>{time.getHours()}</>

        )}

        :

        {time.getMinutes() < 10 ? (

          <>0{time.getMinutes()}</>

        ) : (

          <>{time.getMinutes()}</>
        )}

        :

        {time.getSeconds() < 10 ? (

          <>0{time.getSeconds()}</>

        ) : (

          <>{time.getSeconds()}</>

        )}{' '}

        {time.getHours() >= 12 && time.getHours() < 24 ? (

          <>
            <sub style={{ fontSize: '20px' }}>PM</sub>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <sub style={{ fontSize: '20px' }}>AM</sub>
          </>
        )}
      </>
    ) : (
      <>
        {time.getHours() < 10 ? (
          <>{time.getHours()}</>
        ) : (
          <>{time.getHours()}</>
        )}
        :
        {time.getMinutes() < 10 ? (
          <>0{time.getMinutes()}</>
        ) : (
          <>{time.getMinutes()}</>
        )}
        :
        {time.getSeconds() < 10 ? (
          <>0{time.getSeconds()}</>
        ) : (
          <>{time.getSeconds()}</>
        )}
        <sub style={{ fontSize: '20px' }}>AM</sub>
      </>
    )}
  </h3>
</>
```

);
};

export default WeatherApp;

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Also, you should check how to format your posts properly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Next time I will surely check how to format code on this platform in a proper way

Comment: please add your codes into code fences to increase readablity.